# Getting diff between "dpkg --get-selections" and base on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I know "dpkg --get-selections" will list me installed packages on Ubuntu, but is there a clever way to get the diff between that and the base package.

In other words :

1. I install Ubuntu, say 14.04LTS
2. I install a package, let's say "apt-get install apache"
3. Is there a command I can run that will say "you installed apache after your initial install"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tasksel` to determine list of the packages in the base system.

```
tasksel --task-packages ubuntu-desktop | sort > /tmp/base
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | sort >/tmp/selections
diff -u /tmp/base /tmp/selections | less
```

Use `tasksel --list-tasks` to get the list of tasks.

But the best way to get the manually installed packages list is save `dpkg --get-selection` output immediately after installing the operating system.